# Vega-Altair Conditional Coloring of A line in an multiline chart

Tags: python, visualization, altair, line-plot

I am new user of altair and was trying to understand it's Usage. On the classic cars dataset.

[On the classic cars dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8olTz.png)

SO while doing this I said let's build a linechart and color it by Origin.

```
alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('Year:T', axis = alt.Axis(format=("%Y"))),
    y='mean(Miles_per_Gallon)',
    color='Origin')
```

[This was the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FYRT.png)

Then I thought what if I want to color the lines by a condition like Highlight only one line with red color and all the other lines should have same color.

So I tried this

```
alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
    x=alt.X('Year:T', axis = alt.Axis(format=("%Y"))),
    y='mean(Miles_per_Gallon)',
    color=alt.condition(alt.datum.Origin == 'Europe',
        alt.value('black'),
        alt.value('red')))
```

[This was the result of that. Clearly didn't work out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ditGm.png)

so my question is how do you go about highlighting a single group while fading out other since that's a common practice when you want to highlight something in your analysis. This can be useful in a lot of other visualizations too but I don't understand how to do it. In matplotlib I would just loop through it and put a condition for color so is that the way in altair also or can alt.codition be used in some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

[Finally I was able to solve this by adding a custom column for coloring although I do wonder if there is an easier way of doing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDGHs.png)

```
data['temp'] = data['Origin'].where(data['Origin'] == 'Europe', 
                                      other='Other')

scale = alt.Scale(domain=['Europe', 'Other'], range=['Red', 'grey'])

alt.Chart(data).mark_line().encode(
       x=alt.X('Year:T', axis = alt.Axis(format=("%Y"))),
       y='mean(Miles_per_Gallon)',
       detail='Origin',
       color=alt.Color('temp', scale=scale))
```